# Managing different accounts in Cross Validated

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I have an account in Stack Overflow and as well in Cross Validated with different user id. Is it possible to link the two accounts from different user ID?

If yes , then how to link both the accounts so that I can view all my accounts on the same profile as like below pic:

[image]

Comment: Hey, I recognize those numbers.

Comment: @Glen_b Yeah I had used your account profile for example. I hope you dont have any pbm !! will you?

Comment: No problem as far as I'm concerned, since it's public information - I think anyone with an internet connection can see it already. It was just quite interesting to find the example to be strangely familiar. It took me a while to realize why.

Answer (score 6):

Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts and follow the directions there.

Comment: It seems we can also add : By clicking mylogins link in our account page.Step 1: Click 'my logins' link in your account page.
Step 2: add the other account logins.
Step 3: repeat both the step 1 & 2 in both the accounts(In our case,repeat the step 1 and 2 in both stack overflow and cross validated account)